# Учитывается ли фрагментация индекса при построении плана запроса?

Tags: sql-server

Ну скажем, допустим, есть таблица с "тухлыми" индексами с высокой степенью фрагментации.

Учитывает ли оптимизатор запросов при построении плана фрагментацию или в каких-то случаях он может сказать "Фи.." и проигнорировать индекс?

Comment: Нет, у оптимизатора просто нет времени на оценку фрагментации

Comment: @DenisRubashkin, да, я тоже об этом думал, так как запрос фрагментации у одной таблицы занимает несколько секунд.... Но не может ли она указываться в статистике => оценку делать не нужно живую?

Comment: Такую статейку нашел https://sqlperformance.com/2017/12/sql-indexes/impact-fragmentation-plans

Comment: Ну, по статье фрагментация тоже не рассчитывается - при прочих равных фрагментированный индекс занимает больше страниц, соответственно может быть дороже по чтениям, отсюда и влияние на оценку в плане.

Comment: Ну "пассивное" неявное влияние все таки оказывается.

Comment: Да, лишь косвенное. Плюс, вроде бы, в модели оптимизатора заложено, что seek - рандомный, а scan - последовательный. Но из-за сильной фрагментации сканирование может стать практически эквивалентным рандомному чтению, соответственно стоимость сканирования может быть недооценена.